# Running a Spring Boot App on Azure WebJob with a Schedule

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have a regular Java/Spring Batch job that runs every night to get data from one database and insert/update in my project's database. This is working fine in the current setup where it is deployed on Tomcat.

Now I need to separate it out and run it on an **Azure WebJob**. What will be a good approach?

Can I use Spring Boot for this purpose?
But I am not sure how it will work. I mean, I can create a JAR of my project (Job written using Spring Boot) and copy it on a Azure WebJob. Then have a batch file with "java -jar..." but:

- wouldn't it be like running and deploying the Spring Boot App with it's inbuilt web-server that will continue to run once I run it?
- secondly, the next time the batch file is executed by Azure WebJob as per the schedule I set it will try to run the Spring Boot App again and I will probably get bind exception since the port is already in use from the first run.

Would appreciate if somebody can help me in doing this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> wouldn't it be like running and deploying the Spring Boot App with it's inbuilt web-server that will continue to run once I run it?

A Spring Boot app can be a non web app, and a good example is a Spring Boot batch app without a dependency to a servlet container.

You can create a Spring Boot app that runs your Spring Batch job and then stops when the job is finished without the need to deploy it in a (embedded) Tomcat. You can find an example here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/

> secondly, the next time the batch file is executed by Azure WebJob as per the schedule I set it will try to run the Spring Boot App again and I will probably get bind exception since the port is already in use from the first run.

Once you have a script to run your app with `java -jar mybatchapp.jar`, you can use Azure Scheduler to run your job when you want. Since your batch app does not contain/start an embedded servlet container, you won't get a port conflict.

Comment: thanks for your kind reply, appreciated! By any chance, do you have or know if there is such a sample to read data from one database table to another database table?

Comment: I tried one by following [this](https://www.jackrutorial.com/2018/03/spring-boot-batch-read-from-mysql-database-and-write-into-a-csv-file-tutorial.html) and [this](https://www.jackrutorial.com/2018/03/spring-boot-batch-tutorial-xml-file-to-mysql-database-example.html) links but it's not working. I am just trying to do it in one db, fetch data from one table and insert into other. It doesn't do anything and doesn't give any error also.

Comment: To deploy a web job in azure portal do we  need to create a VPC first . or we can directly deploy our webjob without creating VPC ? kindly suggest