# Azure webjobs with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure, azure-webjobs

I need to run a scheduler for every 1hour, and it has to read DB and send emails. I have deployed my Spring Boot app into Azure webjobs as a scheduled trigger. The app is deployed and the scheduler is working fine, but I don't see the trigger calling my app. Am I doing it correctly?

Also if my understanding is correct , when the trigger starts won't it deploy my Spring boot app again? Please let me know

Since the data from DB is less, I have not preferred to work with Spring Batch

Comment: Any help on this? Please

Answer (score 0):

> Also if my understanding is correct , when the trigger starts won't it deploy my Spring boot app again?

- *yes, you can't deploy **spring boot** application once the trigger is started.*

> The app is deployed and the scheduler is working fine, but I don't see the trigger calling my app. Am I doing it correctly?

- *You can use Maven application Plugin to deploy the spring boot application a you are not using the spring boot batch*
- *Also here is the [Microsoft Official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/deploy-java-spring-boot-app-service-mysql/1-introduction) where you can have a look on connecting the DB with the application and then running the scheduler.*
- *You can even check this Spring Boot deployment [documentation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-azure) and this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51872692) with related discussions.*

Comment: Is there anyway that I can call my call class during every trigger? Please suggest